# Webhooks and Player Integration for Google Classroom

Tags: google-classroom

We have recently started looking into integrating google classrooms with our educational product. Our product allows teachers to create assignments with unique codes which they later give to their students and students using mobile devices and our app submit their work on those particular assignments. Based on how much we have explored google classroom it seems the general architecture  would be sync-able. We are however were unable to find web hooks mechanism in the classroom which we would require to update our system with the latest submissions. Our objective is to keep the system in perfect sync and we would be unable to do that unless the google classroom notifies our platform of every new assignment and / or every submission against an assignment. Could you please guide us to the process from where we can achieve such functionality. One other concern we currently have is that we want to to embed our webGL app in the google classroom as our product submissions are based on those. We would be grateful if you could help us directing us to the resources which would be helpful in integrating these features. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this moment there is no webhooks feature in [Classroom API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191645&template=823908). You can file a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191645&template=823908), as mentioned in their support page. The only available features are that which has been mentioned in the docs.

Comment: ok thank you. I have posted a feature request to them with reference to this thread.